# Embed current View Controller in Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I currently have a single view application which I need to convert to a tab bar application. I'm new to iOS and not quite sure how to embed the current view controller into the controller for the tab bar. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select your view controller and then from Edit, select `Embed In` and then `Tab Bar Controller`

[image]

For more info, you can check this in-detail tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1